# Iterate through dictionary of lists - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have following Dictionary lists

```
dic3 =  {'1': [A1,A2,A4,A6], '2': [A3,A7] ,'3': [A5] }
```

i want to create one more dictionary with key and the first value of the list . Results shown as below

```
dic3 =  {'1': A1, '2': A3 ,'3': A5 }
```

Could you please help me out to achive the same. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: for key, value in res.items()

Comment: Thats not even valid python. [mre] please.

Comment: i have got an answer ..i had deleted the old one..i am extremely sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a dict comprehension:

```py
new_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in old_dict.items()}
```